# How to get group row_number() based on change in indicator column value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have TransactionTime, Amount, and a ResetCountInd (0/1) column.

Goal is to get a running total of Amount column, from one ResetCountInd=0 row until the next.

I understand that if I had a PartitionNumber column, starting numbering where ResetCountInd=0, staying constant until the next, I could easily perform the running total with the window functions.

I'm not understanding how to get this PartitionNumber column. Help?

Visualization of what I'm after. White I have, yellow I don't - PartitionNumber in particular:

[image]

SQL generating sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   TransactionTime datetime NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,ResetCountInd   BIT  NOT NULL
  ,AddedAmount     INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,PartitionNumber INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,RunningTotal    INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(TransactionTime,ResetCountInd,AddedAmount,PartitionNumber,RunningTotal) VALUES ('1/12/16 7:04 AM',0,0,1,0);
INSERT INTO mytable(TransactionTime,ResetCountInd,AddedAmount,PartitionNumber,RunningTotal) VALUES ('1/12/16 9:14 AM',1,50310,1,50310);
INSERT INTO mytable(TransactionTime,ResetCountInd,AddedAmount,PartitionNumber,RunningTotal) VALUES ('1/12/16 12:00 PM',1,276229,1,326539);
INSERT INTO mytable(TransactionTime,ResetCountInd,AddedAmount,PartitionNumber,RunningTotal) VALUES ('1/12/16 1:35 PM',1,45389,1,371928);
INSERT INTO mytable(TransactionTime,ResetCountInd,AddedAmount,PartitionNumber,RunningTotal) VALUES ('1/12/16 1:52 PM',0,0,2,0);
INSERT INTO mytable(TransactionTime,ResetCountInd,AddedAmount,PartitionNumber,RunningTotal) VALUES ('1/12/16 3:35 PM',1,108629,2,108629);
INSERT INTO mytable(TransactionTime,ResetCountInd,AddedAmount,PartitionNumber,RunningTotal) VALUES ('1/12/16 5:04 PM',1,19984,2,128613);
INSERT INTO mytable(TransactionTime,ResetCountInd,AddedAmount,PartitionNumber,RunningTotal) VALUES ('1/12/16 5:44 PM',1,69338,2,197951);
INSERT INTO mytable(TransactionTime,ResetCountInd,AddedAmount,PartitionNumber,RunningTotal) VALUES ('1/12/16 6:17 PM',1,126595,2,324546);
INSERT INTO mytable(TransactionTime,ResetCountInd,AddedAmount,PartitionNumber,RunningTotal) VALUES ('1/12/16 10:59 PM',1,33720,2,358266);
INSERT INTO mytable(TransactionTime,ResetCountInd,AddedAmount,PartitionNumber,RunningTotal) VALUES ('1/13/16 8:57 AM',1,45230,2,403496);
INSERT INTO mytable(TransactionTime,ResetCountInd,AddedAmount,PartitionNumber,RunningTotal) VALUES ('1/13/16 11:00 AM',0,0,3,0);
INSERT INTO mytable(TransactionTime,ResetCountInd,AddedAmount,PartitionNumber,RunningTotal) VALUES ('1/13/16 11:03 AM',1,155323,3,155323);
INSERT INTO mytable(TransactionTime,ResetCountInd,AddedAmount,PartitionNumber,RunningTotal) VALUES ('1/13/16 11:09 AM',0,0,4,0);
INSERT INTO mytable(TransactionTime,ResetCountInd,AddedAmount,PartitionNumber,RunningTotal) VALUES ('1/13/16 12:59 PM',1,67333,4,67333);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group number is the cumulative sum of the indicator being zero.  You can calculate that in a subquery and then use it in the outer query:

```
select t.*,
       sum(addedamount) over (partition by grp order by transactiontime) as runningtotal
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when resetcountind = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by transactiontime) as grp
      from mytable t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution maybe not as neat but works.

```
SELECT 
    mytable.* 
    ,Partitions.*
    ,RunningTot                     = SUM(mytable.AddedAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY Partitions.PartitionNo ORDER BY mytable.TransactionTime) 

FROM mytable

    CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1
                    PartitionNo                          = COUNT(*) OVER(ORDER BY Partition.ResetCountInd)  --Count admin units within the time window in the WHERE clause

                FROM mytable  AS Partition

                WHERE 
                    Partition.TransactionTime <= mytable.TransactionTime

                ) AS Partitions
```

Here's the db<>fiddle [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6f5076d3694c090df11576f138c6431f)